# Mount snap "core" (3887) Error instal vlc 3.0

Tags: vlc

I am trying to install vlc 3.0 stable in Ubuntu 16.04 but it not possible :( This is the error:

```
admin@ubuntu_1604:~/Downloads$ sudo snap install --dangerous vlc_3.0.0_amd64.snap
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (3887) ([start snap-core-3887.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-3887.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-3887.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I can not to install vlc 3.0 official release today in Ubuntu 16.04.
The official repository install to me vlc 2.2.3.

Thank for the little time!! :)

Comment: Did you follow the advise *See "systemctl status snap-core-3887.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details*? You also might consider sharing that information here.

Comment: Hello Thomas, this is information about error:        admin@ubuntu_1604:~/Downloads$ systemctl status snap-core-3887.mount
● snap-core-3887.mount - Mount unit for core
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-3887.mount; enabled; vendor pre
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sáb 2018-02-10 12:20:09 CET; 6min ag
Where: /snap/core/3887
What: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3887.snap
Process: 13112 ExecMount=/bin/mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3887.snap /snap/